# Counting the occurrences of an item in one column for another column's items in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of data in columns. Column a is colour and column b is product.

I wish to count the number of a certain colour for each product in column b

For example: I wish to return how many greens occurred for Product 1, product 2 etc etc using VBA if possible. As a bonus turn all rows for the specific product red colour if there are more than 3 greens for the product

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Green | Product 1 |
| Green | Product 1 |
| Blue | Product 1 |
| Green | Product 2 |
| Red | Product 3 |
| Green | Product 1 |
| Yellow | Product 4 |

I've tried using match and count but can't figure it out

Comment: A Pivot table will show you that information

Comment: Try using COUNTIF()

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in Column c for each row
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Green",B:B,B1)
That will display how many Green there are for that product.

Then highlight columns A:C and add conditional formatting, using a formula to determine which cells to format. Use this as the formula,

=$C1>=3

and then specify the formatting colors you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really easy using a Pivot Table:

[image]

[Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

*using VBA if possible* Sure, post the code you've tried, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting. Or use the macro recorder to create the pivot table and adapt the code to your needs.